# How to properly overlay HTML over canvas with scaling?

Tags: javascript, gui, html, overlay

If I have

```
<div container>
<my html overlay>
<my game canvas>
</div>
```

The canvas has `left: 0; top: 0; width:100%; height:100%; position: relative;`. The div container is a certain width and height that adjusts to aspect ratio based on when the user resizes the screen. On resize I set the official size of the canvas (in three.js, `renderer.setSize`) to the same size to match it up.

This works fine, but then how do I get the html overlay to match the same position it has, over the canvas, when adjusting the size (based on keeping the aspect ratio and scaling in general)?

I think I have to use css scale, but need help in determining what to base the scale factor on.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with game development. You might want to ask this question on StackOverflow or similar platforms.